# Setting an attribute to only allow doubles in a textbox

Tags: c#

I remember using some attribute on the getter/setter that would limit the input to a certain datatype, length etc. IE [Attribute something something].

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to allow scientific notation?  ie: `1.986E-3`, etc?

Comment: No, scientific notation is not necessary. Thank you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean the [`ValidateInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.validateinputattribute.aspx) attribute available in `System.Web.Mvc`?

Also, you could probably use a [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx) if you're doing WinForms.

Comment: MaskedTextBox seems not suitable to me, as it requires a fixed length input (in term of number of characters)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it (if you want to keep using a standard text box) would be to make an event for the text changed event of the text box, and in that, read the text to make sure that it contains only numbers (and an optional period in the case of a double)

Answer (score 1):

Winforms? Have you considered using masked Textbox control?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx

Comment: MaskedTextBox seems not suitable to me, as it requires a fixed length input (in term of number of characters)

Answer (score 0):

Winforms? Why not use a NumericUpDown?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57dy4d56.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx

If you need scientific notation you can do :

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tBox = (TextBox)sender; 

    if (!((e.KeyCode >= Keys.D0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.D9)
       || (e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9)
       || (e.KeyCode == Keys.Decimal && !(tBox.Text.Contains('.')) 
           && !(tBox.Text.Length == 0)
           && !((tBox.Text.Length == 1) 
              && (tBox.Text.Contains('-') || tBox.Text.Contains('+'))))
       || (e.KeyCode == Keys.OemPeriod && !(tBox.Text.Contains('.'))
           && !(tBox.Text.Length == 0)
           && !((tBox.Text.Length == 1) 
              && (tBox.Text.Contains('-') || tBox.Text.Contains('+'))))
       || (e.KeyCode == Keys.Subtract && ((tBox.Text.Length == 0) || 
           tBox.Text.EndsWith("e") || tBox.Text.EndsWith("E")))
       || (e.KeyCode == Keys.OemMinus && ((tBox.Text.Length == 0) || 
           tBox.Text.EndsWith("e") || tBox.Text.EndsWith("E")))
       || (e.KeyCode == Keys.Add && ((tBox.Text.Length == 0) ||  
           tBox.Text.EndsWith("e") || tBox.Text.EndsWith("E")))
       || (e.KeyCode == Keys.Oemplus && ((tBox.Text.Length == 0) || 
           tBox.Text.EndsWith("e") || tBox.Text.EndsWith("E")))
       || e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete
       || e.KeyCode == Keys.Back
       || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left
       || e.KeyCode == Keys.Right
       || (e.KeyCode == Keys.E) && !(tBox.Text.Contains('e')) && 
           (tBox.Text.Contains('.') && !tBox.Text.EndsWith("."))))
        {
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

This will deny input of any pattern which is not consistent with a numeric value.  Minus signs are only allowed at the beginning of the string (to indicate a negative number) and after an `e` or `E` to indicate a negative exponent.  Plus signs follow the same rule as minus.  Only one decimal point is allowed and it must follow at least one number.  Only one `e` or `E` is allowed and it must follow a decimal point and at least one number after the decimal point.

You could also allow things like the `Help`, `Tab`, etc, keys if it would interfere with other aspects of your program function.

Note that this does not prevent incomplete numbers (ie: `1.37E-` or `-13.` from being entered so you would probably want to check the string in any case.  This at least denies any immediately invalid entries.

You might do something like (in the same handler, before the other logic):

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
    textBox1_Validating(sender, new CancelEventArgs());
    return;
}
```

The above only gives the enter key the normal 'feel' for input (force validation).  Leaving the textbox (going out of focus) will also trigger validation where you might do something like :

```
private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tBox = (TextBox)sender; 
    double tstDbl;
    if (!double.TryParse(tBox.Text, out tstDbl)) 
    {
        //handle bad input
    }
    else
    {
        //double value OK
        doSomething(tstDbl);
    }            
}
```

Comment: The purpose is to have two text boxes to set delimiters on a search on double values. I have used the attribute before.

Comment: @Josh - if you don't need scientific notation then I would really suggest the `NumericUpDown` - it is a dedicated numeric control which saves all the intermediate messing around with strings.  You can even set maximum and minimum values (at design time or programmatically) as well as change the number of decimal places you wish to display.  It's really a nice control.

Comment: what about if the user didn't type but just it paste it in the textbox, keydown will not work.